# Evaluating Integrals using Lebesgue Integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose we are to evaluate:

$$I = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$$

Where

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 \space \text{if} \space x\space \text{is rational}, & \newline  0  \space \text{if} \space x \space \text{is irrational} \\ \end{cases}$$

I have been told that this can be done using measure theory.

Will anyone care to explain how possibly? I am new to measure theory, so I am just researching, **please do not say "no attempt shown" this is because I dont know Lebesgue yet, but I heard it has great applications on this?**

Comment: It's trivial using Lebesgue integral results. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @GitGud I am not sure how to do this in any other method, I thought Lebesgue was the best shot. Any alternatives?

Comment: If this is a Riemann integral, you can simply use the definition. However a lot of people answered the current version of the question already, so if you want an elementary (read Riemann integral) answer, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: @GitGud, I was told Riemann is not possible, which is why we turn to Lebesgue?

Comment: It is true that $f$ is not Riemann integrable, but you should understand that working with Lebesgue integrals is working with different objects. The symbols may be the same, but it's a whole different theory (which happens to coincide nicely with R-integrability when the latter exists).

Comment: @GitGud, thanks. How would you evaluate this integral personally? Thanks!

Comment: Lebesgue integral? Like it was done by all the answers below. Riemann integral doesn't make sense. It's you who has to decide what you are working with.

Comment: Just a comment: I don't think anyone nowadays *knows Lebesgue*... I suppose you could have met him when you were $11$ and now be $85$, but I'm guessing no one of that criteria will see this question.

Comment: @DanZimm $\ddot \smile$ I had a lecturer whose father was on a ship with Lebesgue, or so he says.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do: $$\begin{align} \int_{[0,1]} f(x)\, {\rm d}{\frak m}(x) &= \int_{[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q} f(x)\, {\rm d}{\frak m}(x) + \int_{[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q^c} f(x)\, {\rm d}{\frak m}(x) \\ &= \int_{[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q} 1\  {\rm d}{\frak m}(x) + \int_{[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q^c} 0 \ {\rm d}{\frak m}(x) \\&= {\frak m}([0,1] \cap \Bbb Q) = 0 \end{align}.$$

The exact definition of $\frak m$ is: ${\frak m}^*E = \inf\{\sum_{n \geq 1}\ell(J_n) \mid J_n \text{ intervals and } E \subseteq \bigcup_{n \geq 1}J_n\}$. Then ${\frak m}\Bbb Q = 0$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and take a enumeration of $\Bbb Q$, $\{r_1, \cdots, r_n, \cdots\}$. Let $J_n = (r_n - \epsilon/2^{n+1},r_n + \epsilon/2^{n+1})$. Then I leave you to prove that $\Bbb Q \subset \bigcup_{n \geq 1}J_n$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1}\ell(J_n) < \epsilon.$ This in fact proves that any denumerable set has zero measure.

Comment: What does: $[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q$ mean?  Also, how did you split this? Where can I find more beginner information about this?

Comment: $[0,1] \cap \Bbb Q$ means all the rationals in the set $[0,1]$, in the elementary set theory context. The separation $$[0,1] = ([0,1] \cap \Bbb Q) \cup ([0,1]\cap \Bbb Q^c)$$ is just the fact that given a number in $[0,1]$ it is rational or irrational (one only, the union is disjoint)

Comment: The following generally holds: If $A\cup B=C$ and $A, B$ are disjoint measurable sets, then $$\int_Cf\,d\mu=\int_Af|_A\,d\mu+\int_Bf|_B\,d\mu$$

Comment: @IvoTerek, then how did you evaluate the integrals on the RHS?  This is a great answer $(+1)$

Comment: The integral of the zero function is, wait for it... zero, over any measurable set. And the integral of any constant over a measurable set is the constant times the measure of said set.

Comment: The first step of my computation was only using the definition of $f$.. it is $1$ in the rationals and $0$ over the irrationals. You might have fun writing $f(x) = 1$ on the irrationals and $0$ on rationals, then proving that $$\int_{[0,1]} f \ {\rm d}{\frak m} = 1$$

Comment: What about the integral of the $(1)$ why did you multiply by $(0)$ ?? Thanks!

Comment: Because the rationals have zero measure. In the end of the answer there are the steps for proving this :)

Comment: @IvoTerek, these symbols are so alien to me, I have a few more questions, would you mind if I asked? 

How do you find the measure of a corresponding set for **beginners?** Where can I find introductive information on this? Or can you please explain??

Comment: Measure theory is a rather abstract subject, so you won't have to find measures of sets (numerically) often, at least. We work more estimating stuff with inequalities. One of the most important facts about the Lebesgue measure on the line, is that the measure of intervals coincide with their length. You can take a look at Royden's Real Analysis. You can do the theory in $\Bbb R^n$ right away, but if I remember right he starts doing just in $\Bbb R$, you might like it.

Comment: @IvoTerek, I cant prove that $$\int_{[0, 1]} f dm = 1$$ Can you just show me how? This isnt homework, self-interest, I would be very thankful if you can! I can use this for other problems, so if you could show me then that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Up there in my answer, swap $1$ and $0$ in the RHS of the first two lines. What happens next?

Comment: @IvoTerek, I appreciate this help, but this is hard. How does changing $1$ and $0$ change anything?

Comment: $$\begin{align} \int_{[0,1]} f(x)\, {\rm d}{\frak m}(x) &= \int_{[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q} f(x)\, {\rm d}{\frak m}(x) + \int_{[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q^c} f(x)\, {\rm d}{\frak m}(x) \\ &= \int_{[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q} 0\  {\rm d}{\frak m}(x) + \int_{[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q^c} 1\ {\rm d}{\frak m}(x) \\&= {\frak m}([0,1] \cap \Bbb Q^c) = 1 \end{align}.$$

Answer (score 11):

Lebesgue integration tells you that the value is zero. Basically, much like how you can split integrals over intervals in Riemann integration, you can split integrals over arbitrary measurable sets in Lebesgue integration. Here we write:

$$\int_{[0,1]} f(x) dx = \int_{[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}} 1 dx + \int_{[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}^c} 0 dx$$

Now that we've written it as an integral of constant functions, we just multiply the constants by the measures of the corresponding sets, obtaining

$$\int_{[0,1]} f(x) dx = 1 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot 1 = 0.$$

since $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ has measure zero. Explaining how to prove that it has measure zero would require a significant amount of explanation of the definitions and theorems from measure theory.

Comment: what does $[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q$ mean? I am new to measure theory and how did you evaluate the integrals on the RHS (at the top?)

Comment: This is the intersection of set $[0,1]$ and set $\Bbb Q$. And, $\Bbb Q^c$ stands for the complement of $\Bbb Q$, i.e. the set of irrational real numbers

Comment: @Berci  Then how did would you evaluate the integrals?

Comment: @Amad27 Just as the Riemann integral of a constant function on an interval is the constant times the length of the interval, the Lebesgue integral of a constant function on a measurable set is the constant times the measure of the set. In other words the Lebesgue measure is a "generalization of length".

Comment: @Ian, how would I find the measure of the set? and which set?

Comment: In this case the relevant sets are $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$. The former has measure zero, basically because it is countable. Formally, we can enclose it in a countable collection of intervals whose total length is arbitrarily small. Specifically it can be covered by $\{ (q_n-\varepsilon/2^n,q_n+\varepsilon/2^n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ where $\{ q_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an enumeration of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ These have total length at most $2 \varepsilon$, which can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: (Cont.)  The measure of $[0,1]$ is $1$ (its length), so the measure of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$ is $1$ minus the measure of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, that is $1-0=1$.

Comment: If you're still having trouble I would suggest picking up a measure theory text, such as Real Analysis by Royden and Fitzpatrick. This is too complicated of a subject to cram a full explanation into a MSE answer.

Comment: Yeah, I have a lot to read up.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$, from definition of Lebesgue integral you have:

$$I = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx=\lambda(\mathbb{Q\cap[0,1]})=0$$

where $\lambda$ is $1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 4):

Your function $f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$, which is an indicator function of a measurable set. Lebesgue integration tells you that for all measurable $A$, $$\int \mathbb{1}_A dx = \lambda(A)$$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. So, your integral is equal simply to $\lambda(\mathbb{Q})$. One way to see that this is $0$ is by writing $$\mathbb{Q}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{q_n\}$$ with $\{q_n\}$ an enumeration of the rationals, then use the $\sigma$-additivity property of measures noting that the Lebesgue measure of a singleton set is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

The Lebesgue integral is like Riemann integration turned on its side.  (Instead of dividing the domain into sections, as Riemann does, it divides the range into sections and takes the pre-image of those sections.)  It sums the Lebesgue measures of the pre-images of the values in the range of the function times the function values.  It is related to measure theory. In this case, the Lebesgue integral is 1* measure( rationals) + 0 * measure( irrationals).  It can be shown that measure( rationals ) = 0 and measure( irrationals ) = 1.  So the integral is 0.  The measure of the rationals is 0 because you can create a countable set of line segments containing all the rationals whose lengths sum to less than an arbitrarily small epsilon>0.