# Solving this discontinuous integral using Lebesgue

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

**Not a duplicate look at $f(x)$ here!**

Suppose we are to evaluate:

$$I = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$$

Where

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 \space \text{if} \space x\space \text{is irrational}, & \newline  0  \space \text{if} \space x \space \text{is rational} \\ \end{cases}$$

How can I solve this using measure-theory or Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: @Amada27 Is it *imperative* that measure-theory or Lebesgue integrals be used as a solution?

Comment: Look again carefully at the answers to your earlier question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108171/evaluating-integrals-using-lebesgue-integration
...especially Ian's. You should be able to derive the answer using the same logic with small modifications.

Comment: @SimonS sure, Ill try myself, Ill learn better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

1. $\int_{[a,b]}1 dx=b-a$.
2. If $m(\{x:f(x)\neq g(x)\})=0$ then $\int f\,dm=\int g\,dm$.